# how to display an image in a datagrid cell?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

I'm using Compact-Framework 3.5, VS 2008 for Windows Mobile.
I tried something like that:

```
    DataGridTableStyle ts = new DataGridTableStyle();

    DataGridIconColumn dgic = new DataGridIconColumn();
    dgic.ColumnIcon = Properties.Resources.MyIcon;
    dgic.MappingName = "<your_column_name>";
    dgic.HeaderText = "<your_column_header>";

    ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(dgic);

    myDataGrid.TableStyles.Add( ts );
```

After created a DataGridIconColumn Class.

What's the difference between mappingName and headerText property?

Comment: AFAIR MappingName is the name of a datatable column to be used and haederText is what you will see on the screeen.

Answer (score 0):

Write a class that inherits from DataGridTextBoxColumn and overwrite the Paint method to draw whatever you want in the cell. 
This is the signature for the paint method `void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, CurrencyManager source, int rowNum, Brush backBrush, Brush foreBrush, bool alignToRight)`

Use methods provided by the Graphics object g to draw an image.

Use `Object cellData = this.PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(source.List[rowNum]);` to get the data for the cell through what ever property you have set for your column's MappingName.